# How to Call functions in Jade file from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, pug

I am using Jade language in my code. I have written some jade functions with the help of mixin syntax. Now I wanted to call that functions from javascript code.

How do I call ? Can anybody help me please.

```
ul.grid
  each product in products
    +productItem(product)
mixin productItem(item)
  li(style="border: 1px solid #ddd;margin-top: 35px;") #{item}
script(type='text/javascript').
 console.log("Welcome");
 <<How to call productItem function >>
```

I wanted to call the productItem function from script tag where I written 
<> this sentence. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call Pug mixins with JS. And mixins aren't functions either. That said, you can include Javascript in a mixin like this:

```
mixin productItem(item)
   li(style="border: 1px solid #ddd;margin-top: 35px;") #{item}
   script.
      console.log("This will be logged once each time this mixin is called.");
```

Is it correct to assume, that you would like to include JS in your PUG mixin?

Btw, [Jade is now Pug](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2184). Cheers!